# How to start a new Wordpress website from scratch while the old version is still live?

Tags: wordpress

I was tasked with re-making the website for a startup, but it seems like it is very difficult to work with the old version that was passed on to me from older interns. The current Wordpress website is filled with all sorts of plugins which I am unfamiliar with. When I try to change a theme, for instance, it messes up everything.

I want to start it from scratch. However, I don't want to take the old version offline while I work on it. I want to remove all of the plugins and start from the very beginning, while also having the old version live for visitors, and maintaining all the content there while I work on a completely new website. How can I do that?

Comment: Develop new site on localhost

Comment: Develop in a development enviroment. Staging site, localhost. There are many ways of doing this. Copy a version of the live site - set it up in a hidden site and make your changes.

Comment: Install Docker or Vagrant to develop at local env. And create a subdomain like staging.yousite.com - don't forget to disallow robots for this subdomain

Comment: Isn't it enough to make a subdomain and create the website there? I don't have any experience using development environments :(

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, congratulations on taking the right decision of creating the website from scratch. Updating or upgrading a loosely managed wordpress website can be a nightmare.

Well, there are other comments to your question, you have multiple options to start the fresh development. I would recommend setting up development environment very similar to your live environment. That includes, the platform and server on which the current live website runs (like, Windows or ubuntu, IIS or Apache or Nginx etc.), the php version and configuration. That way you will be able to minimize the issues/problems that might occur while launch the new website.

I would also recommend to do a requirement analysis of the existing plugins and do away with unnecessary ones. I think, when it comes to plugins, its always lesser the better.

If you are using any professional theme, make sure to create its child theme and use the child theme. That way, when the parent theme is updated you will not loose any customizations you have made in your child theme.

I suppose you will maintain the hierarchy of pages and respective URL structure. When you properly maintain these things, you are less likely to run into 404 errors for pages after publishing the new website. If you are merging any pages/URls are getting rid of stale content, you will need to note those URLs and put an appropriate direct after new site is published.

If the current website is already registered and authenticated with webmaster tools / analytics tools, you will need to inherit the authentication methods (like, the authentication meta tag or analytics code or an html file etc.)

As I am not aware about your proficiency in wordpress, all these points might seem very basic for you, but still thought to put it anyway.

I guess irrespective of any development environment, URL of the new website in database will be like "*not-your-main-domain.com/page-slug-url/*". So, when publish your website you will need to change the URls in database. Following utility might come handy for that.
https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am a pretty much a beginner when it comes to making websites (outside of website builders), so none of what you mentioned is basic to me haha! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new site in a subdomain, another server, or even on a local server. Once the new site is built you can then migrate(move, copy) it to the live site's location. There are some tools out there to help with moving the site you can use once the site is done. Some require a plugin to be installed to do that though. For example magicmigration can be used to move the completed site to a new location (that one specifically doesn't take extra installs). It is also possible to manually migrate the site though depending on the situation and know-how that can be a bit much for some people.